# Hunspell - Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named en_US

Tags: hunspell

I'd like to use hunspell to spell check my repo. However when I try to run it I get the following error:

```
Can't open affix or dictionary files for dictionary named "en_US".
```

How can I fix this? I'm on a Mac.

Thanks, Kevin

Answer (score 44, accepted):

Execute `hunspell -D`. You should get output like this:

```
.::/usr/share/hunspell:/usr/share/myspell:
/usr/share/myspell/dicts:/Library/Spelling:

AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
/Library/Spelling/en_GB
LOADED DICTIONARY:
/Library/Spelling/en_GB.aff
/Library/Spelling/en_GB.dic
```

This lists the directories in which `hunspell` is searching for dictionary files, as well as the dictionaries is has found. If the dictionary `en_US` isn't listed, you haven't got that particular dictionary installed.

To install a dictionary, search for it in the [LibreOffice extension repository](https://extensions.libreoffice.org/). Download it then extract the `.aff` and `.dic` files to one of the locations listed by `hunspell -D`. For example:

```
# First download dict-en.oxt
unzip dict-en.oxt -d dict-en
cp dict-en/en_GB.aff dict-en/en_GB.dic ~/Library/Spelling/
rm -r dict-en
```

Comment: Link no longer has .aff or .dic files, just .oxt (Open Office extension). I was able to find them in the Chromium source: chromium/src/third_party/hunspell_dictionaries/en_US.dic

Comment: .oxt files are just ZIP files.  You can change the extension and open them and retrieve the files.  If you do that, you can stay up to date by watching the extension page for updates.

Comment: Btw, on macOs latest Hunspell is broken. For more see: https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell/issues/608

Comment: I was able to get Hunspell working on macOS by following these answer's instructions, with the exception of the link for the `.aff` and `.dic` files. To get these I followed the instructions found at https://github.com/hunspell/hunspell#usage (minus the hash pin). So in short I used:
`wget -O en_US.aff  https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.aff` and `wget -O en_US.dic https://cgit.freedesktop.org/libreoffice/dictionaries/plain/en/en_US.dic`

Comment: Worked for me on Amazon Linux, Downloaded from the following sources and added both to the path "/usr/share/myspell": https://github.com/elastic/hunspell/blob/master/dicts/en_US/en_US.aff and https://github.com/elastic/hunspell/blob/master/dicts/en_US/en_US.dic

Answer (score 2):

I'm using emacs in windows using msys2. I installed following 2 packages:

```
pacman -S  mingw-w64-x86_64-hunspell-en mingw-w64-x86_64-hunspell
```

The mingw-w64-x86_64-hunspell-en package install english dictionaries in /mingw64/share/hunspell, but you check if the files (en_US.dic and en_US.aff) are available or not.

Steps:

1. set the Environment Variable in .bashrc within mysys2. Without DICPATH it was not working for me.

   ```
   export DICTIONARY=en_US
   export DICPATH=/d/../msys2/ming164/share/hunspell
   ```
2. run hunspell.exe -D

   ```
   SEARCH PATH:
   .;... ;...;...
   AVAILABLE DICTIONARIES (path is not mandatory for -d option):
   D:/xx/mysys64/mingw64/share/hunspell/en_AG
   D:/xx/mysys64/mingw64/share/hunspell/en_AU
   ...
   ```

   Hunspell 1.6.0

Comment: This is perhaps due to a [bug](https://github.com/Alexpux/MINGW-packages/issues/2147).  When it's resolved, the workaround shouldn't be needed but still thanks for this.

Answer (score 0):

I was lucky to find my language here: https://extensions.openoffice.org/en/search?query=de_CH&sort_by=field_project_stats_year&sort_order=DESC

And with the comment from @RobDavenport i was able to rename the extension and extract the files. Something i reread at this [link](https://tinyspell.com/hunspell.htm) and gave it a try.
I dropped the .dic .dat and .aff into my ~/Library/Spelling/ folder.